# PHP inline value evaluation

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter and i am using the following snippet is part of an edit form. What it does is to take a value to edit, and populate the field. The same form-builder is used to rebuild the form when there are validation errors, and the fields will be repopulated values that may or may not have been edited by the user.

```
$field = form_input(array(
    'name' => 'title',
    'id' => 'title'
 ), set_value('title') || 'givenValue') <-- this part
```

in CodeIgniter, `.set_value()` just returns a string that was a value of some form field if the form had an error (basically used for repopulating the fields after an error).

i know that in JavaScript i can do like `var someObj = param.obj || {}` which will result into `someObj` equals `param.obj` if it exists or equals to `{}` otherwise. In PHP snippet above, it returns `1` (boolean i suppose).

In summary, I want to have the former value if it exists, or if not, use a predetermined value (additionally, a blank value if it's the new form)

How do I do this "inline evaluation" in PHP? or is there a better way to do this in CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update

According to the [manual](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html), CI already provides a *default* option for you

```
set_value('title', 'givenValue')
```

---

In pure PHP, if you're using PHP 5.3, you can use the ternary shortcut

```
set_value('title') ?: 'givenValue'
```

otherwise, try the long version

```
set_value('title') ? set_value('title') : 'givenValue'
```

Comment: i know that the second parameter is the default value. I just needed to use an existing value from a failed validation if there was one, or use a default.